# Amazon scrape 403 error: The request could not be satisfied

Tags: php

When I try to scrape amazon.com, I'm getting this error.

**403 ERROR
The request could not be satisfied.**

This is the curl code for scraping

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, "80");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, "username:password");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.1224.87 Safari/547.36 OPR/43.0.2442.45");


$result['EXE'] = curl_exec($ch);
$result['INF'] = curl_getinfo($ch);
$result['ERR'] = curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $result;
```

But, when I try other Amazon domain, like .fr, or .in it works well. Is this something with Amazon or my script?

Answer (score 0):

Simply lookup the HTTP-Code and you'll find:

> 403 Forbidden
>   The request was valid, but the server is refusing action. The user might not have the necessary permissions for a resource, or may need an account of some sort.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Your IP may be already banned, that's why Amazon offers APIs.